# How to parse this xml using c#

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing

I want to parse this xml in c# using LINQ. I have input as placemark name 'RFA13'.
I want to get the coordinates node for this input value.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
            <name>EQDemo</name>
            <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
            <Folder>
                <name>Untitled layer</name>
                <Placemark>
                    <styleUrl>#line-000000-4</styleUrl>
                    <name>RFA13</name>
                    <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                            <LinearRing>
                                <tessellate>0</tessellate>
                                <coordinates>-97.77405023574829,30.27369885454351,0.0 -97.79602289199829,30.261244946171974,</coordinates>
                            </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                    </Polygon>
                </Placemark>
            </Folder>
            <Folder>
                <name>Untitled layer</name>
                <Placemark>
                    <styleUrl>#line-000000-4</styleUrl>
                    <name>RFA14</name>
                    <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                            <LinearRing>
                                <tessellate>0</tessellate>
                                <coordinates>-97.76755392551422,30.284103698805,0.0 -97.77020126581192,30.279346144221726,0.0 -97.77405023574829,30.27369885454351,0.0</coordinates>
                            </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                    </Polygon>
                </Placemark>
            </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus you have xml namespace declared in your `kml` element, then you should use it for providing names of elements:

```
string name = "RFA13";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(); // get namespace
// find placemark element with name you provided
var placemark = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Placemark")
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => (string)p.Element(ns + "name") == name);

if (placemark != null) // check if placemark found
{
    // assume every placemark has coordinates
    string coordinates = placemark.Descendants(ns + "coordinates")
                                  .Select(c => (string)c)
                                  .First();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XDocument` and XPath:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");

var coordinates = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(@"Document/Folder/Placemark[name = 'RFA13']/Polygon/outerBoundaryIs/LinearRing/coordinates");
```

You'll need both `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Xml.XPath` imported by `using` at the top of the file.

Comment: It is giving value as null

Comment: So your document does not look like the one you've posted. I tested it with given XML and it returns proper `coordinates` element.

Comment: sorry, forgot to update kml node